# After opening a new project, the screen shows black and only outlines with no textures nor gridlines. Is there a setting that i need to change?

Tags: texturing, error

Is there any way i can show the screen?
After opening a new project, the screen shows nothing but outlines, even with newly added objects. This is a freshly installed Blender without any setting changes since i'm just starting to learn blender. I use a Windows 8.1 and Blender 4.0.
Blender 4.0.2
CPU : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3240 @3.10Ghz
RAM : 8 GB DDR3
GPU : AMD Radeon R7 200 Series
GPU Driver version : 13.251.9001.1001
Blender from Blender.org
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/znK5h.jpg

Comment: Check that your GPU and driver is supported by Blender 4. This is the section about AMD cards in the [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#hip-amd).

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)